# Passing a string to Helm parameters via ArgoCD? Overriding values.yaml

Tags: arrays, string, yaml, helm3, argocd

I am trying to create a manifest that will override certain values in a helm chart using ArgoCD to manage the deployment of the helm chart. For the most part this is easy to do, that is until I want to pass a string. I am having trouble with the following.

```
 apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: vault
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: hashicorp-vault
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm
    targetRevision: "v0.21.0"
    path: .
    helm:
      parameters:
        - name: server.ha.config
          value: | 
            listener "tcp" {
              address = "[::]:8200"
              cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
              tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.crt"
              tls_key_file  = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.key"
              tls_client_ca_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.ca"
            } 
  destination:
    name: hashicorp-vault
    namespace: hashicorp-vault
```

When I pass a string as a value I get the following error, "Expected:[null,array], given: string" and I think I understand this, but I also lack the knowledge to resolve it. Basically I am trying to override the values.yaml [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/blob/main/values.yaml) via ArgoCD and there is a section under server.ha.config where I need to supply certificate information and override the default configuration. However I am unsure of how to do this without creating a duplicate github repo and modifying the values.yaml   .

Below is how the actual Chart.yaml is formatted for what I am trying to override.

```
server:
  ha:
    config: | 
      ui = true
      listener "tcp" {
        tls_disable = 1
        address = "[::]:8200"
        cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
      }
      storage "consul" {
        path = "vault"
        address = "HOST_IP:8500"
      }
      service_registration "kubernetes" {}
```

I hope I have provided enough information.

Comment: I have the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74389660/rewrite-helm-values-yaml-via-argocd