# Rewrite helm values.yaml via ARGOcd?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I am installing metric server by using ARGOCD application. I can add values via:

```
helm:
  values: |
    args:
    - --kubelet-insecure-tls=true
```

But how can I rewrite values as the above method just add a new value but now rewrite the default one?